# Angular 6 - Event emitter from submodule to parent module

Tags: angular

I have a project structure like below

```
src
  -> app
        -> ui
             ->header
             ->layout
             ui.module.js
    app.component.css
    app.component.html
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
```

In header folder i have html,css, and ts files. in ts file i have a variable to emit to parent (app.component.ts)

My "header" ts file emitter code as below

```
@Output() highlightedMenu1 = new EventEmitter<string>();


somemthod(s : string){ //this some method will be called on click event from "header" html
    this.highlightedMenu1.emit('hi'); //wanted to emit this variable to app.component.ts
}
```

My "header" html file emitter code as below

```
(highlightedMenu1)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"
```

"ui.module.js" exported both "header" and "layout".

in app.component.ts declared a method like below

expecting this method to be called. from "header" html, but it was not calling, instead if i have this method in my "layout" module emitter working fine.

```
getMenuBarSelected(s: string) {
    console.log('string =========* ');
  }
```

"app.module.ts" i have imported "UiModule"

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint to make sure that your event that should be calling the `somethod(s: string)` method is actually being called? Your highlightedMenu1 event emiiter should be working correctly, though I wouldn't advise having numerals in any kind of function or variable names. If the method is getting called to emit, try changing the highlightedMenu1 to highlightedMenuOne and see if that works any differently.

Comment: somemethod is called successfully. highlightedMenu1 rename also done, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Output` allows **parent** to subscribe to an EventEmitter declared in its **child**.

---

If header.component.ts is having `highlightedMenu1`

```
@Output() highlightedMenu1 = new EventEmitter<string>();


somemthod(s : string){ //this some method will be called on click event from "header" html
    this.highlightedMenu1.emit('hi'); //wanted to emit this variable to app.component.ts
}
```

Header.component.html can't have following because its part of same component:

```
(highlightedMenu1)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"//wrong
```

Rather, some parent component can have as follows:

**layout.component.html**

```
<app-header (highlightedMenu1)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"></app-header>//right
```

assuming `getMenuBarSelected` is defined inside `layout.component.ts`

---

**Edit:**

`@Output` events dont bubble like, say, `click` event etc. So there is no way for grandparent to know if an event was triggered in grandchild. However, you can create another @output event inside direct parent so that grandparent can listen to then.

**Assuming:**

**app.component (grandparent) -> layout.component(parent) -> header.component(child)**

In addition to above code, you need:
layout.component.ts

```
@Output() highlightedMenu1 = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

layout.component.html

```
<app-header (highlightedMenu1)="highlightedMenu1.emit($event)"></app-header>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-layout (highlightedMenu1)="myMethod($event)"></app-layout>
```

---

**Another simpler way** to is to have some `EventService`.
**EventService.ts**

```
static highlightedMenu1 = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and in **header.component.ts**

```
   myMethod(){
       EventService.highlightedMenu1.emit('hi');
   }
```

and in **app.component.ts**

```
EventService.highlightedMenu1.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

---

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uh5pr3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fui%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html)

Comment: i have tries this approach also "<app-header (highlightedMenu1)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"></app-header>", if i have "getMenuBarSelected" defined inside "layout.component.ts" it is working, but what i expect  is, i want to access event emitter variable from header.component.ts to app.component.ts not from "layout.component.ts"

Comment: It is never reaching app.component.ts method. added code like "<app-header (highlightedMenuone)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"></app-header>" in layout.component.hrml. AND <app-layout (highlightedMenuone)="getMenuBarSelected($event)"> in app.component.html AND getMenuBarSelected(s: string) {

    console.log('string =========* ' + s);
  } in app.component.ts

Comment: its not highlightedMenuone but highlightedMenu1. I have created a stackblitz. check my edit